# PHP Looping data when a form have a different name attribute every each row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I make a loop of data when the form I created the data displayed requires a different `name` attribute ?

I make a jQuery code to create elements like:

```
$("#loadDataSiswa").append(""+
    "<div class='grid_2xxx kekiri'>" + nm_depan + "</div>"+
    "<div class='grid_5xxx kekanan'> \n"+
        "<input type='radio' name='"+id+"' value='1'> Masuk"+
        "<input type='radio' name='"+id+"' value='2'> Tidak Masuk"+
        "<input type='radio' name='"+id+"' value='3'> Sakit"+
        "<input type='radio' name='"+id+"' value='4'> Tidak Ada Kabar"+
    "</div>"+
"");
```

`id` and `nm_depan` values already done with ajax process.

If you look at the code above, I have to make it with a different attribute name for the form to be displayed should be like this
[image: Multiple Group]

Form I created to produce radio element that should be selected each row

```
foreach($_POST as $val) {
    // Insert to DB
}
```

Here I get into **trouble**. How do I make a loop to get the value of `id` will I do insert into the database if a particular `id` selected value? How does in PHP to loop with a different name attribute? Because here, I'm changing the name of each attribute using the `id` that I get from the ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be resolved associating a hidden input with some radio group.

Add a hidden input with `id` value:

```
"<input type='hidden' name='radioList[]' value='" + id + "'" />"
```

This input is an array, so you can iterate through.

On next step you have to modify your radio group to associate with your `id`:

```
"<input type='radio' name='myradio["+id+"]' value='1'> Masuk"+
"<input type='radio' name='myradio["+id+"]' value='2'> Tidak Masuk"+
"<input type='radio' name='myradio["+id+"]' value='3'> Sakit"+
"<input type='radio' name='myradio["+id+"]' value='4'> Tidak Ada Kabar"+
```

So in your code you should be able to do:

```
//Iterate through any inserted id from a group
foreach($_POST['radioList'] as $id)
{
    //if you didn't let any pre checked value, you need use this if
    if(isset($_POST['myradio'][$id])
    {
        echo $_POST['myradio'][$id];//checked value this group
    }
}
```

After all you should be able to have any quantity of radio buttons associated to an infinity list

Comment: Do you mean, I must add `<input type='hidden' name='radioList[]' value='" + id + "'" />` every loop my data? And create code to set value from radioButton checked into the hidden field?

Comment: @BerthoJoris Yes, you have to add the hidden input in every loop to associate with the radio options. No, you don't need to create a code to check, just the name of radio group must be associate with the id from the hidden input, like I did `name="myradio[the id/value from hidden input]"`

Comment: Hai @gab.....With your sample code I can see loop result with ID from input. But how I can combine with radio checked?

So that I could distinguish the data `ID` and `VALUE` of the radio. I want to make it become `ID_VALUE` format inside loop. And then in php I can break it down using the `explode`

Comment: ops, I did a mistake, you have to use: `$_POST['myradio'][$id]`, I'll update the code above

Comment: How if I want to get `ID_VALUE` format from looping ? Current, I only get a radio `VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

To get the keys in the post var try this. $key holds the name attribute (javascript id var) from the Form.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

    if($key == "whatever") ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial name selectors.
Please refer to this https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
Or you can give a class to the inputs just to loop them.