# What's the cleanest way to implement a dynamic HTML form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

I want to make a HTML form where the user can edit a set of elements at once. The user has to be able to remove an element, edit element and add new elements. I'm using PHP (Laravel) as a backend and jQuery for the dynamic form.

My initial idea was do basically this:

```
<form id="bars">
    @foreach($foo as $bar)
        <input type="text" name="name[]" value="{{$bar->name}}" required>
        <input type="color" name="color[]" value="{{$bar->color}}" required>
        <input type="checkbox" name="completed[]"{{$bar->completed ? ' checked' : ''}}>
        <span class="deleteRow"></span>
    @endforeach
</form>

<div id="template" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="name[]" required>
        <input type="color" name="color[]" required>
        <input type="checkbox" name="completed[]"{{$bar->completed ? ' checked' : ''}}>
        <span class="deleteRow"></span>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Remove rows
        $('form').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        // Clone new rows from template
        $('#addRow').click(function() {
            $('#template tr')
                .clone()
                .appendTo('#bars');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the Blade template from which I've removed all irrelevant code and styling. This approach uses the following concepts:

- `[]` in the input names so that the POSTed data will be placed into an array. In processing I end up with three arrays `name`, `color`, and `completed` which will contain the POSTed data.
- Existing elements are rendered server-side in the form by the Blade template
- New rows are cloned from a 'form template' and added to the form when the user clicks the "new row" button.

This is quite simple, and works in most cases (I've used this before), but it does not work in this case because of a small thing: the checkboxes. Unchecked checkboxes will not be POSTed which means that in the `completed[]` array will be smaller in size than the other arrays and I have no way of checking which elements have the checkbox checked.

Now I could modify my JS in such a way that it keeps track of the indexes and explicitly inserts the index in every input name (so `name[0]`, `name[1]`, etc) but that approach is complicated by the fact that the form must be pre-filled with data and does not start out empty.

I can, instead of filling the data through the Blade template, let the JS handle that too (through a JSON API) but that also gets complicated fast because the JS now has to 'parse' the form template and fill in all the values.

What's the best practise to accomplish this in a clean way?

Comment: change `(document).ready( ... )` to `$(document).ready( ... )`

Comment: Ah, of course I meant that ;) It was just an error in copy-pasting the code. I've edited the question.

Comment: Oh hahah :D I'm looking through your code, and everything seems fine :/ are you sure you have **everything** included that is necessary?

Comment: Seems fine in what way? It's not that the code is not running. It's an implementation question I'm asking; this proposed solution does not work in my case because I have checkboxes that break the `[]` approach in the input names. (checkboxes that are unchecked are not POSTed)

So I'm looking for another, clean approach that does not have this problem.

Comment: You can set an index to your dynamic fields, like: `name[1]` and `checkbox[1]` (to add some kind of relation). Then when you loop your arrays in the back end, you can see what checkbox (if any) is related. You would need to print that index in your initial loop and then dynamically add it when you add new elements from your template.

Comment: assigning some value to the false condition, i.e., `checked? 'checked' : 'no'` would fix right?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, that's what I already proposed in my question. However, this is complicated by the fact that I have pre-existing data that needs to be rendered in the form. I don't know how to handle that in a clean way.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny No, that would simply cause the string "no" to be inserted into the <input> tag if the condition is false (like `<input name="foo" no>`, which is invalid HTML of course.

Comment: what about a space instead of null?

Comment: I don't see why that should make any difference? Like I said, you add index in your blade loop. Then you continue on the index in JS when you add new elements? Also adding a hidden field named: `id[index]` will let you know what ID the field has (if it comes from a DB). If ID doesn't exist, then it was dynamically added.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny What exactly would that accomplish? The rendering of the "checked" attribute based on the completion status is not the problem. The problem is with POSTing the form and the input name `[]` array approach.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Alright, I get what you mean. I'll need to get the value of the latest index in my JS code somehow. That's possible to do, but I'm wonder if what I'm doing is best practise. It all seems "hacky", if you know what I mean.

Comment: No, it's development. Sometimes you need to be creative. Specially if you want to build dynamic features like this. There aren't always a "pretty" solution for every case.

Comment: Here, it's about radio, but is the same principle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930940/php-looping-data-when-a-form-have-a-different-name-attribute-every-each-row/40931513#40931513

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with is the following:

```
<form id="bars">
    @foreach($foo as $i => $bar)
        <input type="hidden" name="id[{{$i}}]" value="{{$status->id}}">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[{{$i}}]" value="{{$status->name}}" required>
        <input type="color" name="color[{{$i}}]" value="{{$bar->color}}" required>
        <input type="checkbox" name="completed[{{$i}}]"{{$bar->completed ? ' checked' : ''}}>
        <span class="deleteRow"></span>
    @endforeach
</form>

<div id="template" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="name[$i]" required>
        <input type="color" name="color[$i]" required>
        <input type="checkbox" name="completed[$i]"{{$bar->completed ? ' checked' : ''}}>
        <span class="deleteRow"></span>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Remove rows
        $('form').on('click', '.deleteRow', function() {
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });

        // Clone new rows from template
        $('#addRow').click(function() {
            $('#template tr')
                .clone()
                .html(function(i, oldHTML) {
                    return oldHTML.replace(/\$i/g, $('#bars tr').length);
                })
                .appendTo('#bars');
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is mostly what @MagnusEriksson advised me to do (so thanks!) but solved in a slightly cleaner way by not having to keep a counter but simply using the number of rows inside the form as the index for the cloned rows.